# Shrink binary image to non-zero area in python

Tags: python, arrays

I have this array:

```
a = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
     [0,0,1,7,1,0,0],
     [0,0,1,3,0,0,0],
     [0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,4,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

And I would like to get the smallest array, with not deleting any elements !=0.

```
 result = 
    [[0,1,0,0],
    [1,7,1,0],
    [1,3,0,0],
    [1,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,4]]
```

My solution is:

```
for i in range(0, np.shape(a)[0]):
    if np.sum(a[i,:]) != 0:
        i_begin = i
        break

for i in range(np.shape(a)[0]-1, -1, -1):
    if np.sum(a[i,:]) != 0:
        i_end = i
        break

for j in range(0,np.shape(a)[1]):
    if np.sum(a[:,j]) != 0:
        j_begin = j
        break

for j in range(np.shape(a)[1]-1, -1, -1):
    if np.sum(a[:,j]) != 0:
        j_end = j
        break

print(a[i_begin:i_end+1, j_begin:j_end+1])
```

But this looks pretty silly to me and not like good coding style.

Is there a better way to do that?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25710356/numpy-given-the-nonzero-indices-of-a-matrix-how-to-extract-the-elements-into-a . Does it solve your problem?

Comment: No, because I don't want rows of just 0s in the mid of the matrix being deleted. It's about getting like a frame for the whole picture. But thank you anyways

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly then. The solution in the linked thread will preserve rows/columns of only 0s in the middle, e.g `[[0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 1 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 0 0]]`  as input will give you `[[1 1 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 0]]` as output. Isn't that what you're looking for?

Comment: yes that's right. I was just wondering about whether there is a shorter solution without for looping every side. But in the end it's working, you're right